# Save data from an API to a JavaScript (Js) array and export as a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I want to fetch data from an API and save it as a component in my react app, such that I will be able to export this component into other components and as such tap in into its data from each of those other components.

To do this, I tried using this code:

```
var data=[] ;

async function add(){
try {
    const response = await  fetch('https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=all#')
const json = await response.json()
console.log(json)
    for (var i=0; i<json.length; i++){
        data.push(json[i])
    }
    return data
}catch(error){
    console.log("error", error)
}    
}


add();


export default data;
```

This however doesn't seem to work well as it records a data length of zero in other components but when logged in the console, it gives the actual length of the array.

Please help me out.

Comment: _"I want to fetch data from an Api and save it as a component"_: that's not really how React works. You'll probably want to fetch the data in a parent component, save it in state, and then have your components read from that state and update if/when it changes.

Comment: Make your data a global variable and update it when you make an API call. It can be done but this is not a traditional way of react as @Andy suggested above

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Could you please help me out with probably a code because I attempted using hooks but I got stuck in the way. I got stuck in a way that to me I think I will have to be writing the hooks in every component and I feel this shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

let's say you are having your function at util.js as follow

```
var data=[] ;

async function add(){
try {
    const response = await  fetch('https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=all#')
    const json = await response.json()
    for (var i=0; i< json.length; i++){
        data.push(json[i])
    }
    return data
}catch(error){
    console.log("error", error)
}    
}


export default add;
```

and in your place where you want to use as follow

```
import add from './util.js';

add().then((data => console.log(data)))
```

Comment: Why `node-fetch`? The browser already has `fetch`.

Comment: yes that's not needed. I usually test on node :)

Comment: Thanks but this isn't working I even typed in the console.log(await add ()) inside one of the components I was rendering, and it gave an error: `Unexpected reserved word 'await' ` 

And plus, I'm actually trying to access the data, not the add function. Like if you check the API, I want to tap into the score and show fields such that for instance, if I type `data.show.name`, it will give me the data there. or will add().show.name give me the same value?

Comment: you can try `add().then((data => console.log(data)))`

Answer (score 0):

Use a parent component with state to act as the "single source of truth" for the data. Use [an useEffect hook](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) to initially load the data from the API into state at which point the components that rely on that data will re-render. In this case `List` will render a list of show names wrapped in an anchors pointing to the show URL.

Note: I've had to use conventional `fetch`...`then` in this contrived example as snippets don't like `async/await` but you can swap that out should you prefer.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

// Pass in the API endpoint to the App component
function App({ api }) {

  // Initialise state
  const [ data, setData ] = useState([]);

  // Using an empty dependency array (`[]`) so that the effect
  // runs _once_ when the component is mounted call `getData`
  // with `fetch` then parse the data, then set the state
  // with `setData` using the parsed data
  useEffect(() => {
    function getData(api) {
      fetch(api)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setData(data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
    getData(api);
  }, []);

  // If `data` is empty just return a "Loading"
  // message for the time-being
  if (!data.length) return <div>Loading</div>;

  // Otherwise render the List component passing in
  // the state as its data property
  return <List data={data} />

}

// List accepts a data property, and you can `map`
// over that array to produce a list of anchored items
function List({ data }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map(obj => {
        const { show: { url, name } } = obj;
        return (
          <li>
            <a href={url}>{name}</a>
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}

const api = 'https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=all';

// Pass in the API endpoint as an App property
ReactDOM.render(
  <App api={api} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Additional documentation

- [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked but however, its not really what I wanted. I wanted to be able to fetch the data from the api, then save it in an array say like `var data =[]`. Thwn it is this `data` that I will now export to other components, in this case to pages. I want to be able to use it in pages like a normal offline JSON object array such that I will now render the pages  in react router and nothing (I mean no code) will be in the APP.js other than the routes.

Comment: And that's why I've not yet accepted your answer. Or should I just believe that this isn't possible in reacts like @Andy and **Shashank** earlier said on this page.

Comment: I _am_ Andy :) The short answer is no, you can't store data in a global array like you do with vanilla JS - in React if you want to store data to be available to other components it must be stored in state. Now how you do that is up to you. This was a small example using a parent to store the state but there are other state libraries (Redux, Recoil, Zustand etc) that can help with that. You just need to make a choice of the approach that is best for you. @DamilolaAdebayo

Comment: Wow! Thanks. I never knew you were the one who wrote me the code, I just noticed it now . Thanks. I've seen a material at https://betterprogramming.pub/setting-up-dynamic-routing-in-react-23ca07d59057 to help me do this like you said because I wanted to render the components (in this case, the pages) inside react-router. I believe with this alongside your response(s) is an excellent way to go. Many thanks, @Andy.

Answer (score -1):

You can make a ***function*** for an api call and use it anywhere in you component like below

```js
async function add(){
try {
    const response = await  fetch('https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=all#')
const json = await response.json()
return json.data;
}catch(error){
    console.log("error", error)
}    
}

export default add;


import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import add from './add';

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect( async()=> {
  const result =  await add();
  setData(result);
  },[])
  return (
    <> 
{data.map((item) => <h1>item[anyKeyIfExist]<h1>)}
  </>
);
};
```

Comment: [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002). It will stop the errors appearing in your snippet.

Comment: Pls I understand the code up to before this `{data.map((item) => <h1>item[anyKeyIfExist]<h1>)}`
This is actually what I want to do, I want to map each of the values in the API into space `div` block  using  **scores** as the key and have `show.name` and `show.summary` rendered on the webpage. How can I access these values. That's my challenge. Kindly view the API. Thanks

Comment: You have to use the state in order to display the dynamic data. 
just use the above function and save the data into the state. 
e.g 
`{data.map((item) => <div>item.name<div>)}`

Comment: Thanks for this, I copied this code but it said there was no complete tag for `div` in `<div>item.name<div>` so i fixed that by adding / to the last `div`.

However an error still persists around the **async** function in the **useEffect** hooks and I've not gotten a way around this.